# Why can't I control the speed of my CPU fan?

Tags: fan, speedfan, cpu-cooler

I bought a new computer with an [ASRock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASRock) H61M motherboard and XILENCE ICEBREAKER 64 Pro PWM CPU FAN. The problem is that **I can't control the speed of the FAN**.

I tried settings in the BIOS and with SpeedFan as well as with ASRock extreme tuner. After applying the new configuration the fan is still rotating at **full speed** (around 2,100 RPM).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does the fan connect to for power: the mainboard or a powersupply lead?

Comment: The fan is connected to the mobo to the cpu_fan input and it has 3 wires. I can read actual rpm of the fan in BIOS and in the software, I just can't change the speed.

Comment: 4-pin socket on the mobo?

Comment: Yes, the cpu_fan socket has 4 pin but the fan has only 3 wires.

Comment: http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_%28CPU%29_4_Pin_Fan "Note: when using a 3-pin power connector with a 4-pin fan header, the fan will always be on; there is no fan control."

Comment: thx aki, if you move the comment as an answer i can set it up as a proper respond/answer to the question.

Comment: Are there any other 3-pin fan headers on the motherboard? If so try plugging your cpu fan into one of those. Your bios may complain about there being no cpu fan installed, in which case there should be an option somewhere to ignore it.

Comment: nope, all fan sockets are 4 pins. I think i got wrong fan, since PWM indicates that it can be controlled and thus it should have 4 pins.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*"Note: when using a 3-pin power connector with a 4-pin fan header, the fan will always be on; there is no fan control."*

http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_%28CPU%29_4_Pin_Fan

Answer (score 15):

A three-pin fan connector does not include the ability to control speed dynamically, since it lacks the appropriate [PWM control logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) in the fan itself.  [PWM fans](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/REV1_2_Public.pdf) require explicit support from both the motherboard and fan itself.

If you wish to slow your CPU fan down, you can install a [resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor) along the the *power* wire (+12V) in the fan.  Alternatively, you can purchase a LNA (low-noise adapter), which is essentially the same thing (although it saves you soldering in a resistor yourself).  Due to the tachometer sensor discussed in the next section, you cannot put the resistor on the ground wire.  You could also install a hardware fan controller (which is also essentially a resistor, albeit a variable one called a [potentiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer)).

If you're interested in determining how to slow your fan down with a resistor (it's honestly pretty easy), I have provided calculations at the bottom of this answer.  Alternatively, you could use a potentiometer (and use these calculations to provide a rough estimate of the range of resistance needed).

**If you do choose to slow your fan down** (usually for noise purposes), do ensure that your load temperatures do not get too hot.  Slowing down your fan will lower the efficiency of your heatsink's ability to dissipate heat... This is the classical noise versus heat debate all over.

---

For those wondering *why* a fan with no speed control even has three wires, the third wire is used as a tachometer output signal.  Since it is tied to the same power rail as the motherboard, there is no need for an additional ground wire.  According to the fan specifications I linked to above, the standard is to provide two "pulses" per revolution.  The motherboard (and your hardware monitoring software) can then infer the speed of the fan from the rate of these voltage "pulses".

(I say "pulses" because the [tachometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachometer) pin is [pulled high](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor) by the motherboard, and every time it is "pulsed", the fan pulls the pin to ground, or 0V - and this is why you can't put a resistor on the ground wire if you want to slow the fan down).

---

To calculate the resistor you need (to put in series with the +12V wire), first determine the fan's voltage and power draw (usually listed on the fan itself).  Let's assume the the fan runs on +12V, and draws 1W, and we want to slow it down to 75% of the original speed (or, drop the power down to 0.75W).

The original internal resistance of the fan is given by R = V<sup>2</sup>/P (a variation of [Ohm's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) and [Joule's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%27s_Law)), and the new resistance we need will be R = V<sup>2</sup>/(0.75P).  Thus, we need a resistor of size:

R<sub>new</sub> = V<sup>2</sup>/(0.75P) - V<sup>2</sup>/P = V<sup>2</sup>[(1/0.75P) - (1/P)].

Plugging in our numbers, we get R<sub>new</sub> = 12V<sup>2</sup>[(1/0.75W) - (1/1W)] = 48 Ohms.  Thus, you would need to put a 48 Ohm resistor in series with the +12V fan supply to slow it down by 75% (assuming it originally draws 1W).  If you have a soldering iron and some heatshrink/electrical tape handy, the resistor should cost you no more then $0.15 - just make sure the resistor is rated to at least 0.75W (preferably 1W).

Comment: Enjoyed the answear, +1 for me.

Comment: Nice and detailed answer. Thanks. I am familiar with electronics and your solution, I just think it is not a good idea to do that.

Comment: @user20196 I would argue that it has little to do with being a good/bad idea... Adding a resistor/potentiometer is all that fan controllers or (U)LNA adapters do (except they cost a lot more then fifteen cents).

Comment: @Breakthrough the difference is that you have feedback loop which controls the rpm of the fan. Setting the fan to 800 rpm may cause, in some cases, CPU overheating.

Comment: @user20196 I don't see any feedback loop here - there is no input to change the system variables, the CPU fan is at a constant rate.  I did, however, update the question to mention that if you do change your CPU fan speed, to ensure that your load temperatures stay cool enough - good point.

Answer (score 0):

I have AMD stock cooler with 4 pin fan. It runs by default between 1600 -3300 RPM (PWM controlled). Now, I have managed to increase RPMs all the way to 6136 RPM (Note: CPU still varies the fan speed according to core temperature, but in different RPM ranges).

I have gained control of fan RPMs with intervention on fan PCB electronics, by adding RESISTOR and POTENTIOMETER in parallel with SMD RESISTOR on fans PCB.

**NOTE: Value of fan resistor is 5 Kohm; Value of added resistor is 10 Kohm; Value of added potentiometer is 10 Kohm (Potentiometer is in series with 10 Kohm resistor and than both of these are in parallel with fan resistor). I have also installed a switch to have turn off possibility of added circuitry (Off = default)**

Turning the potentiometer towards higher resistance increases RPMs and vice versa. Now, when computer add his pulses when temperature increases, fan RPMs raises too and vice versa.

RPM range control with potentiometer is between min/max: 3300 - 6136 (6136 RPMs are on 100 % CPU load when the potentiometer is set on maximum value of 10 Kohm).

**So in practice it's like this:**

**Turbo fan operations mode switch - ON & STOCK with RPM range adjustment possibility (potentiometer).**

**ON MODE (potentiometer in zero position): Min/Max RPM: 3300 - 5000; Potentiometer in Max position: Min/Max RPM: 4436 - 6136. STOCK MODE (Switch Off): Min/Max RPM: 1600 - 3300. In every RPM range CPU variate fan speed according to core temperature.**

**However, in your case, to decrease fan speed ranges, you must replace FAN SMD RESISTOR with one which has higher resistance value, in that way that keep RPMs below 2100.**

**Also, if you wish to have automatic fan RPM control (fans with 3 wires), you'll need to install PTC resistor somewhere near the CPU, since PTC resistors changes its resistance (towards higher values) with raise of temperature, therefore fan RPM will also variate according to CPU temperature.**

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP has a 3-pin fan so your answer doesn't apply to him.

Comment: @DavidPostill, you are right, I've further explained according to this particular topic question.